# Destroy PDO connection?

Tags: php

I have a layer class like this:

```
class Database extends PDO
{

public function __construct($connection)
{
    parent::__construct(DB_TYPE . ":host=". $connection['host'] .
        ";dbname=" . $connection['dbName'], $connection['username'], $connection['dbPass']);
}
```

how I can unset the connection in the `destruct`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The connection remains active for the lifetime of that PDO object. To
>   close the connection, you need to destroy the object by ensuring that
>   all remaining references to it are deleted--you do this by assigning
>   NULL to the variable that holds the object. If you don't do this
>   explicitly, PHP will automatically close the connection when your
>   script ends.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Note that if you initialise the PDO object as a persistent connection it will not automatically close the connection.

Refer the example below for using connection in classes

```
class Db
{
    # Class properties
    private $DBH; // Database Handle
    private $STH; // Statement Handle

    # Func: __construct()
    # Desc: Connects to DB
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Connection information
        $host   = 'localhost';
        $dbname = 'removed';
        $user   = 'removed';
        $pass   = 'removed';

        // Attempt DB connection
        try
        {
            $this->DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
            $this->DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo 'Successfully connected to the database!';
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    # Func: query(sql statement)
    # Desc: Sends a query to the DB
    public function query($sql_statement)
    {
        $sql = array(':color' => $sql_statement);
        $this->STH = $this->DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO color_table (color) value ( :color )");
        $this->STH->execute($sql);
    }

    # Func: __destruct()
    # Desc: Disconnects from the DB
    public function __destruct()
    {
        // Disconnect from DB
        $this->DBH = null;
        echo 'Successfully disconnected from the database!';
    }
```